# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx' with my custom type in Visual Studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I try to run the code below by clicking the red box `Run Python File` in the screenshot below :

**car_client.py**

```
from MyLib.car import Car

car = Car()
print(car.get_name())
```

But I get the error below:

> ```
> from MyLib.car import Car
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyLib'

**car.py**

```
class Car:
   def get_name(self):
      return 'BMW'
```

[image]

**Update**

@JialeDu's answer is good, but requires making the change to every file. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the top of the code in the **car_client.py** file:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("./MyLib")
```

and modify the **import** as

```
from car import Car
```

the code will work fine

[image]

Comment: This answer requires making the change to every file. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score -2):

To make it a module, you need to define an `__init__.py` file.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages